# Create simple embedded http and https applications in C#

Tags: c#, http, webserver

There is a simple [http server API](http://blogs.oracle.com/michaelmcm/entry/http_server_api_in_java) that allow you do some [simple stuff](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/LightweightHTTPServer.htm) quickly, without any addition dependency/installation required.

Are there any similar API/library in .NET ***WITHOUT IIS***?

For example, I am a small window service running, I'd like to add a simple stupid web interface to allow local/remote control/monitoring.

Comment: Since XP SP2 is an issue, you might want to define minimum system requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) hooks into HTTP.SYS even without IIS, I believe.

You'll need to add priveleges to the service account, though - `netsh` on vista, `httpcfg` on xp ("how" covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169904)).

Comment: Thanks. But they have note on the MSDN website: You will get a PlatformNotSupportedException before WinXP SP2.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to find a sockets-based library... oh well.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the previously mentioned [webserver project on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/webserver), which I've used in a production application, another simple HTTP server API option is [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/). Kayak appears to be in an early development stage. It hasn't reached 1.0 yet.

UPDATE: I noticed that my original link to Kayak broke recently. The main website for Kayak has moved to http://kayakhttp.com/ but the code is hosted on Google code: http://code.google.com/p/kayak/.

UPDATE 2: Apparently, the Kayak source code has moved yet again, this time to GitHub: https://github.com/kayak/kayak/.

UPDATE 3: the webserver is "being migrated" to a networking library, also at GitHub: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.networking

Comment: update 2011-01-18:  I did some research and noticed and that the author (Benjamin van der Veen) of Kayak says, he "no longer feel that C# is well-suited to writing user-facing web frameworks." ... from his post:  http://groups.google.com/group/kayak-http/browse_thread/thread/bbadf8266ecaa830

Comment: Given the frequent relocation of the source code, and the shifts in focus and direction of the author, I'm not convinced Kayak is suitable for production projects. I personally prefer the C# Webserver project on Codeplex for real-world applications.

Comment: And too bad that the webserver project on codeplex is listed as inactive/abandoned now as well.

Comment: Ah, that's sad. Hopefully someone with the time will resurrect the C# webserver project. There's definitely a need for something like this in the .NET stack.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google gave me many examples of this, such as [Creating your own web server using C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/article.php/c4603).

Note, that is a very old article, there are probably more concise ways to do this now.

Edit: another nice example [here](http://www.codeplex.com/webserver).