# How can I publish a web page from a Windows Forms application? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, html

I wish to build a Windows application that will generally run in the background, but have a configurable front-end Windows Forms GUI. I also would like this program to publish a small web page which can be accessed from other machines/devices and interact or call functions of the server application.
I'd rather not deploy a full-fledged ASP.NET web site with IIS, etc. I just need something simple.

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean hosting a web server in your application to serve some static HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458036/create-simple-embedded-http-and-https-applications-in-c

Comment: That question pointed me to a CodePlex HttpClient which worked perfectly for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kev in the comments on my question, he pointed me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458036/create-simple-embedded-http-and-https-applications-in-c), in which I found a link to a lightweight C# HTTP server component I could just drop in to my application: http://webserver.codeplex.com/

Works well for little stuff like I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/).  It's a relatively small and lightweight HTTP server that you can embed into your application and should provide all the functionality you're looking for.

FWIW, I am in no way associated with this project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just because i've been doing asp dev for years, but I really think you should go the iis asp route as its very simple and built into windows. I can't imagine a more straightforward way of serving a webpage that has c# behind it to programmatically effect the host system.