# Why do I get "AccessDenied" when trying to use HttpListener?

Tags: .net, web-services, sockets

Win 7 and VS2010 B2. I am trying to write a minimal web server using the built-in `HttpListener`. However, I keep getting an AccessDenied exception. Here is the code:

```
    int Run(string[] args) {

        _server = new HttpListener();
        _server.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9669/");
        _server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server bound to: {0}", _server.Prefixes.First());

        _server.BeginGetContext(HandleContext, null);
    }
```

I could understand the need to run as administrator if I was binding to a system port, but I don't see why my binding to 9669 should require special permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks to this SO question: [Can I listen on a port (using HttpListener or other .NET code) on Vista without requiring administrator priveleges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169904/can-i-listen-on-a-port-using-httplistener-or-other-net-code-on-vista-without-r)

I have an answer.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:9669/ user=fak listen=yes
```

Crazy. Here is my revised function:

```
    int Run(string[] args) {

        var prefix = "http://*:9669/";
        var username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
        var userdomain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN");

        _server = new HttpListener();
        _server.Prefixes.Add(prefix);

        try {
            _server.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException ex) {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 5) {
                Console.WriteLine("You need to run the following command:");
                Console.WriteLine("  netsh http add urlacl url={0} user={1}\\{2} listen=yes",
                    prefix, userdomain, username);
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                throw;
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Server bound to: {0}", _server.Prefixes.First());

        _server.BeginGetContext(HandleContext, null);
    }
```

Comment: more security for us all to learn

Comment: It does appear that you really need the `listen=yes`. Worked for me without it. Also, I used `http://+:9669/`.