# which ASP.NET hosting site allows listening on different ports than 80 and uses .NET 4?

Tags: sockets, html

I'm trying to take advantage of HTML 5 web sockets in .NET and the easiest way appears to be something like what [this guy does](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/c_sharp_web_socket_server.aspx?msg=3485900#xx3485900xx).

I've already tested this myself and it works great, but there are a few problems if I try to deploy this to my hosting site (discountasp.net).  Basically, I am not allowed to open up a port on 8080 and listen on it.  I then tried to figure out a way to listen on port 80 with IIS as well, but using the HTTPListener, I run into sercurity issues as well. This doesn't seem like it will help since [I can't mess with this stuff on the hosting site server either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169904/can-i-listen-on-a-port-using-httplistener-or-other-net-code-on-vista-without-r).

So to make my life easier, I think I need to find a hosting site that simply allows me to open up a socket on port 8080 and listen on it.  Anyone know of one? Or does anyone know of a workaround (besides sniffing **all** the traffic on port 80)?